# YII2 Log target don't check the Category of log and save any Category logs

Tags: logging, yii2

I use this config for Yii2 logging

```
 'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error'],
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                'levels' => ['info',],
                'categories' => ['myLog'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I need save "error", "waring" and only my (not application) logs in database.

On localhost it works correct. But when i move project to host, log with level "info" and category "application" appear in db. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there are no other configs that are applied on your host env?

Comment: Absolutly, becouse I've copied and pasted project "as it is", i.e with no changes

Comment: Ok, so maybe this is a config for one of the applications you have (like `frontend`, `backend`, etc.) and logs are coming from different ones?

Comment: No, i use basic project